# ValueError: shapes (80,15) and (16,1) not aligned: 15 (dim 1) != 16 (dim 0)

Tags: excel

I want code for bpnn neural network. An error occured "ValueError: shapes (80,15) and (16,1) not aligned: 15 (dim 1) != 16 (dim 0)" How to fix this problem?

for itr in range(iterations):

```
# feedforward propagation
# on hidden layer
Z1 = np.dot(x_train, w1)
A1 = sigmoid(Z1)

# on output layer
Z2 = np.dot(A1, w2)
A2 = sigmoid(Z2)


# Calculating error
mse = mean_squared_error(A2, y_train)
acc = accuracy(A2, y_train)
results=results.append({"mse":mse, "accuracy":acc},ignore_index=True )

# backpropagation
E1 = A2 - y_train
dW1 = E1 * A2 * (1 - A2)

E2 = np.dot(dW1, w2.T)
dW2 = E2 * A1 * (1 - A1)


# weight updates

#weight changes
W2_update = np.dot(A1.T, dW1) / N
W1_update = np.dot(x_train.T, dW2) / N
#new weight
w2 = w2 - learning_rate * W2_update
w1 = w1 - learning_rate * W1_update
```

I tried to reshape the data but somehow it couldn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.